# How can I capture and send raw mouse input in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I know how to capture mouse movement in general, relative to the screen, but what about in games where mouse movement is being used independently from the mouse's position on the screen?

For example, in a game your cursor is hidden but you can keep moving your mouse to the left infinitely and turn in circles, far further than there's room for your mouse to move on your screen. The game might lock your invisible mouse into the center, or let it move until it hits the edge of the window, but at that point any attempt to record the mouse's movement relative to the screen is useless.

So how can I capture / send raw mouse input. For example if I want to tell the player to turn 1000 degrees to the left via mouse input and record the mouse input from a player turning 1000 degrees to the left, how can I do both of those things?

My goal is ultimately to record a player's various control including mouse input to create one of those systems which record and play back user input. I've searched all over the ahk docs and Google and found nothing about capturing and sending raw mouse input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been taken care of for you by a fantastic user on the AHK forums named evilC.

It's called [mouse delta](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=10159) and tracks changes in raw mouse input.

I've posted one of the few different variants of his mouse delta script. Make sure you follow the link above to see all the different ones he has done.

Again, this is not my work.

```
; Instantiate this class and pass it a func name or a Function Object
; The specified function will be called with the delta move for the X and Y axes
; Normally, there is no windows message "mouse stopped", so one is simulated.
; After 10ms of no mouse movement, the callback is called with 0 for X and Y
Class MouseDelta {
    State := 0
    __New(callback){
        ;~ this.TimeoutFn := this.TimeoutFunc.Bind(this)
        this.MouseMovedFn := this.MouseMoved.Bind(this)

        this.Callback := callback
    }

    Start(){
        static DevSize := 8 + A_PtrSize, RIDEV_INPUTSINK := 0x00000100
        ; Register mouse for WM_INPUT messages.
        VarSetCapacity(RAWINPUTDEVICE, DevSize)
        NumPut(1, RAWINPUTDEVICE, 0, "UShort")
        NumPut(2, RAWINPUTDEVICE, 2, "UShort")
        NumPut(RIDEV_INPUTSINK, RAWINPUTDEVICE, 4, "Uint")
        ; WM_INPUT needs a hwnd to route to, so get the hwnd of the AHK Gui.
        ; It doesn't matter if the GUI is showing, it still exists
        Gui +hwndhwnd
        NumPut(hwnd, RAWINPUTDEVICE, 8, "Uint")

        this.RAWINPUTDEVICE := RAWINPUTDEVICE
        DllCall("RegisterRawInputDevices", "Ptr", &RAWINPUTDEVICE, "UInt", 1, "UInt", DevSize )
        OnMessage(0x00FF, this.MouseMovedFn)
        this.State := 1
        return this ; allow chaining
    }

    Stop(){
        static RIDEV_REMOVE := 0x00000001
        static DevSize := 8 + A_PtrSize
        OnMessage(0x00FF, this.MouseMovedFn, 0)
        RAWINPUTDEVICE := this.RAWINPUTDEVICE
        NumPut(RIDEV_REMOVE, RAWINPUTDEVICE, 4, "Uint")
        DllCall("RegisterRawInputDevices", "Ptr", &RAWINPUTDEVICE, "UInt", 1, "UInt", DevSize )
        this.State := 0
        return this ; allow chaining
    }

    SetState(state){
        if (state && !this.State)
            this.Start()
        else if (!state && this.State)
            this.Stop()
        return this ; allow chaining
    }

    Delete(){
        this.Stop()
        ;~ this.TimeoutFn := ""
        this.MouseMovedFn := ""
    }

    ; Called when the mouse moved.
    ; Messages tend to contain small (+/- 1) movements, and happen frequently (~20ms)
    MouseMoved(wParam, lParam){
        Critical
        ; RawInput statics
        static DeviceSize := 2 * A_PtrSize, iSize := 0, sz := 0, pcbSize:=8+2*A_PtrSize, offsets := {x: (20+A_PtrSize*2), y: (24+A_PtrSize*2)}, uRawInput

        static axes := {x: 1, y: 2}

        ; Get hDevice from RAWINPUTHEADER to identify which mouse this data came from
        VarSetCapacity(header, pcbSize, 0)
        If (!DllCall("GetRawInputData", "UPtr", lParam, "uint", 0x10000005, "UPtr", &header, "Uint*", pcbSize, "Uint", pcbSize) or ErrorLevel)
            Return 0
        ThisMouse := NumGet(header, 8, "UPtr")

        ; Find size of rawinput data - only needs to be run the first time.
        if (!iSize){
            r := DllCall("GetRawInputData", "UInt", lParam, "UInt", 0x10000003, "Ptr", 0, "UInt*", iSize, "UInt", 8 + (A_PtrSize * 2))
            VarSetCapacity(uRawInput, iSize)
        }
        sz := iSize ; param gets overwritten with # of bytes output, so preserve iSize
        ; Get RawInput data
        r := DllCall("GetRawInputData", "UInt", lParam, "UInt", 0x10000003, "Ptr", &uRawInput, "UInt*", sz, "UInt", 8 + (A_PtrSize * 2))

        x := 0, y := 0  ; Ensure we always report a number for an axis. Needed?
        x := NumGet(&uRawInput, offsets.x, "Int")
        y := NumGet(&uRawInput, offsets.y, "Int")

        this.Callback.(ThisMouse, x, y)

        ;~ ; There is no message for "Stopped", so simulate one
        ;~ fn := this.TimeoutFn
        ;~ SetTimer, % fn, -50
    }

    ;~ TimeoutFunc(){
        ;~ this.Callback.("", 0, 0)
    ;~ }

}
```

Comment: How do you use this tho?